# Installing relatively modern texlive on Raspbian

Tags: texlive-2019

My version or Raspbian comes with TL 2016. It does not work with my documents and I need to upgrade. How can I install TL 2019 if its binary platform does not include ARM?

Comment: Can't you update your Raspbian? Or the newer Raspbian (it's Raspberry Pi OS now) doesn't come with newer TeXLive? Then, probably you could build TeXLive from sources. Or you could install Debian on it: https://wiki.debian.org/RaspberryPi. (Every suggestion takes significant efforts though.)

Comment: Excellent questions, comrade! 1) No, I cannot update.2) No, I am not building TeXLive from sources on Raspberry Pi. Not in this life. Maybe in the next life, when I am an immortal unicorn, I might consider it, but not now. Bottom line, none of this answers the question.

Comment: It wasn't an answer, just merely a comment. By the way, TeXLive 2020 distribution includes binaries for the armhf architecture. They might work on Raspberry Pi (at least for some of them).